# Is it normal for a sprinkler system to increase water pressure to a house?

Tags: water-pressure, sprinkler-system

I'm having a sprinkler system installed and the PSI meter in my garage went from 85 psi to about 105 psi. Is it expected that a sprinkler system increases water pressure to my house? If not, is adjusting the pressure release value a reasonable approach to fix it?

Comment: Lawn sprinklers I take it?

Comment: Is this pressure reading with the water running anywhere or with no flow? If the heating of water trapped in the sprinkler system is the mechanism for increased pressure, then immediately after briefly running each zone in turn the pressure should be lower and then increase with time as the trapped water would increase in temperature.

Comment: An even easier test would be if the pressure reading is elevated, run the water in the house anywhere, then shut off the flow. Is the pressure now reduced?

Comment: AFIK all irrigation systems have a check valve to prevent backflow into the supply system. This should prevent trapped water from exerting backpressure. Also isn't the water in the irrigation lines at 0 psig after the water is shut off? If the lines heat up, wouldn't water just dribble out the heads or orifaces?

Comment: @JimStewart, yes it depends on how the system is built. If there is an external feed line before the control valve it will be pressurized and subject to heating.

Comment: But pressurization of the house piping still requires there to be a check valve between the house and the city water lines. Are there such check valves? If not, something else is going on here.

Comment: I confirmed with the city that 105-110 psi is what's provided in my area. They speculate my home's water pressure reducing valve is not working properly. But I'm still wondering where the PSI jump came from.

Comment: I don't know the actual probabilities on what could go wrong with your house's pressure reducing valve (I didn't know you even had one), but just speculating the pressure reducing valve may have gotten particulate matter in it or gotten damaged when the irrigation installer turned the water off and back on. Do you know where the pressure reducer is located? Did the city have any advice on how to restore function? Could you operate without it or would this cause damage or impair function? What is the pressure rating of the flexible hoses for clothes washer and other hoses you may have?

Comment: I'm trying the pressure reducing valvue; like the PSI gauge, it's in my garage. I started it around 64 psi, it's creeped up to about 68 psi but seems to be holding there. The city had no advice; once it's past the water main, it's not their problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can, if you live in a hot sunny climate and there is no one-way valve to the sprinkler system. Cold water in, or on their way to the sprinkler valves will be heated by the ground or sun, and expand will a little causing significant back pressure.

If you have ever left your garden hose filled with water with the hose bib shut off on a sunny day, then pulled the trigger on the hose end, you will see the same effect. Lots of water pressure.

Answer (score 1):

Sprinklers usually drop your pressure while on but other than that there should be no change in pressure. I am thinking of lawn sprinklers.